# How to Filter grouped query result set (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, postgresql

I've done a query like this :

```
SELECT Code,
       kind,
       SUM(valP) AS value 
FROM transaction 
WHERE tp = 'N' and date = '20110312' 
GROUP BY Code,kind ORDER BY Code,kind;
```

on a database table that give me this resultset :

```
+------+------+------+
| Code |  kind| value|
+------+------+------+
|  1   |  TR  | 25,99| 
|  1   |  CT  | 22,17| 
|  2   |  TR  | 14,23| 
|  3   |  DD  | 09,67| 
|  3   |  DD  | 23,87|
|  3   |  CT  | 34,87|
+------+------+------+
```

The code represent a transaction code, kind represent payments type, and value represent the value of the payments.

I want to inclue in the result set only the grouped result that contain a kind type = 'CT' but i want to include also the other payments kind in the same transaction, for example i've tried by adding an having to the upper query:

```
SELECT Code,
       kind,
       SUM(valP) AS value 
FROM transaction 
WHERE tp = 'N' and date = '20110312' 
GROUP BY Code,kind HAVING kind = 'CT' 
ORDER BY Code,kind;
```

but i obtain something like this :

```
+------+------+------+
| Code |  kind| value|
+------+------+------+
|  1   |  CT  | 22,17| 
|  3   |  CT  | 34,87|
+------+------+------+
```

instead i want to retrieve something like this :

```
+------+------+------+
| Code |  kind| value|
+------+------+------+
|  1   |  TR  | 25,99| 
|  1   |  CT  | 22,17| 
|  3   |  DD  | 09,67| 
|  3   |  DD  | 23,87|
|  3   |  CT  | 34,87|
+------+------+------+
```

All lines of the transaction that have within a record with type CT , is there a way to obtain this ?

How can i do ?

I'm actually working on a SQL Server 2005 but i may need run a similar query in PostgreSQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add condition that tells "This Code must have a row with CT" sa do a sub-query:

```
SELECT Code FROM transaction WHERE kind='CT' GROUP BY Code ;
```

And to your first query add a filter to show only those records which have Code in previous subquery:

```
... AND Code IN (SELECT Code FROM transaction WHERE kind='CT' GROUP BY Code ) ...
```

This will get rid of record Code 2, because 2 will no be in results from first query

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT Code,
       kind,
       SUM(valP) AS value 
FROM transaction 
WHERE tp = 'N' 
  AND date = '20110312' 
  AND code IN (SELECT t2.code
               FROM transaction t2
               WHERE t2.kind = 'CT')
GROUP BY Code,kind 
ORDER BY Code,kind;
```